# Getting text to appear below a picture

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys so i am trying to get some text to appear below a picture i have using bootstrap version 3

**So far i have :**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><img alt="my image" class="img-about" src="Images/s1.fw.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2>aa</h2>
        </div>
```

But so far its appearing side by side, but i would like it to appear below each other So the picture on the top and then text below e.g

```
Picture 
-Text
```

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want them side by side, why are you using the column classes?

Comment: @TiesonT. I am planning to have 3 pictures on the same line spaced out with text underneath them if that makes sense

Comment: It does, but then the image and text should be in the same column container, if that's what you're after. You might also want to look at the card class in the Bootstrap 4 alpha.

Comment: @TiesonT. Im an idiot , thanks so much :0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your text to be underneath the image, don't put it in the separate column.

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
       <img alt="my image" class="img-about" src="Images/s1.fw.png"></div>
       <h2>aa</h2>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        // Use this for seconfd image in the right of the 1st one.
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for a different approach. [More](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
p {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #666;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px 0 50px;
}

   

.grid {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  padding: 30px;
}

.fluid-flex {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  /* Not supported by Safari */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col fluid-flex">
    <h1>My Image 1</h1>
    <img src="https://s.zkcdn.net/Advertisers/cd7db6dc529e4cd3a3b9483b34465631.png" alt="Image" title="Image" />
    <p>This was taken when i was in TX.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col fluid-flex">
    <h1>My Image 2</h1>
    <img src="https://s.zkcdn.net/Advertisers/cd7db6dc529e4cd3a3b9483b34465631.png" alt="Image" title="Image" />
    <p>This was taken when i was in CA.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col fluid-flex">
    <h1>My Image 3</h1>
    <img src="https://s.zkcdn.net/Advertisers/cd7db6dc529e4cd3a3b9483b34465631.png" alt="Image" title="Image" />
    <p>This was taken when i was in NY.
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without bootstrap:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}  

img {
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 2px;
}  

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img alt="my image" class="img-about" src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg">
  <h2>Some Text</h2>
</div>
```